# C programming - assigning a character to braille dots

Tags: c, arrays, string, braille

I'm completely new to C and I'd love to learn ways to go about doing this. I'm writing a program that takes in letters and numbers and outputs their corresponding braille "cell", which is a 3x2 rectangle.

"a" in braille is ⠁

"b" is ⠃

In Java, I was going about solving it by using a 2D array for each character. Each **@** represents a braille dot. Each period represents an empty placeholder:

```
    String[][] a = {{"@", "."},
                    {".", "."},
                    {".", "."}};

    String[][] b = {{"@", "."},
                    {"@", "."},
                    {".", "."}};
```

So on and so forth. And I would use nested for loops to print the rows and columns in a grid format.
Is there any better/more efficient way to go about this in C?

Bonus question... For printing, ideally I would want them to be side-by-side grids, so "abc" would print as **⠁⠃⠉**, as opposed to having them separate on each line. But I'm not sure how to print grids to the same "line".

Answer (score 1):

For a start you don't need to store strings - why not just chars?

To print on the same line you need some sort of collection of "BrailleChars" then print "row 0" of each char in the collection, then "row 1" of each one etc rather than trying to print each character in it's entirety before moving on to the next one.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Could you please elaborate as to how I would set, for example, a  = ⠁? I do understand unsigned char arrays. I have created one with hexadecimal values; (0x01, 0x03...). Just fuzzy on how to set *this* character to *this* grid.

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers your query or not: `braileChar[0][0] = '.'; brailleChar[0][1] = ' ';`

Comment: Thank you, I will do some testing with that